# What are the differences between index databases and property databases in SharePoint2010 search?

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

What are the differences between  index databases and property databases in SharePoint2010 search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx

**Search service application Crawl database**

The Crawl database stores the state of the crawled data and the crawl history.

**Search service application Property database**

The Property database stores information that is associated with the crawled data, including properties, history, and crawl queues.